# async layout switch with left shift and right shift Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm transitioning from Windows to Ubuntu and would like to replicate the same functionality I had on my Windows machine using a special layout switcher called `Keyla`. This switcher allows me to enable the `en` layout by pressing the <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> key, and subsequent <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> key presses do not alter the layout. On the other hand, pressing the <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> key activates the `es` layout and also ignores repeated key presses, providing me with certainty about the current layout in use. For instance, I can press the <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> key once and be confident that I am typing in the `en` layout.

I've attempted various suggestions provided by ChatGPT, but none of them have proven successful. The closest solution I found was using `xcape` with a bash script, but it appears to be impossible to execute a bash script in this context. Furthermore, when I use the command `setxkbmap -layout` to change the layout, the system's layout indicator remains unchanged. Additionally, I cannot switch layouts using the default switcher (<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) and can only do so by using the `setxkbmap` command with a different layout.

I'm uncertain whether this is the correct approach, so I'm wondering if anyone else has already configured such settings or knows precisely how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Finally I wrote a little service that implements such layout switch scheme. https://github.com/dreamscatchers/layout-switcher